# why is robots.txt important? is it safe to have a website without robots.txt?

Tags: html, node.js, web, sitemap, robots.txt

While scraping the web robots.txt matters and even regulates behavior. But for a node.js website is it necessary to have a robot's.txt?
Further what is a sitemap and why is it needed as i found in the below example?

```
User-Agent: *
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*/ivc/*
Disallow: /users/flair/
Disallow: /jobs/n/*
Disallow: /jobs/a/*
Disallow: /jobs/companies/n/*
Disallow: /jobs/companies/a/*
Sitemap: https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml
```

i have gone through several links and wanted a short solution.
further if i don't have a robots.txt, is my website more prone to danger?

Comment: Read about robots.txt: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro

Read about sitemaps: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/overview

Comment: This question is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. 

Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sitemap` is an XML file which contains a list of all of the webpages on your site as well as metadata (metadata being information that relates to each URL). In the same way as a `robots.txt` file works, a sitemap allows search engines to crawl through an index of all the webpages on your site in one place.

Comment: for more information check this post https://youbiquity.co.uk/articles/content-hub/how-to-add-your-sitemap-to-your-robots-txt-file/#:~:text=A%20sitemap%20is%20an%20XML,your%20site%20in%20one%20place.

Comment: thanks! and sorry for late reply, but can you tel me weather lack of robots.txt causes any security problem?

Comment: No there is no security issue it's helps to improve SEO performance

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your help. Please upvote the question for helping me as I am banned from asking question due to this question. Thanks in advance.